# How to update mongodb with angular nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

My wish is to be able to update my mongodb using angularjs on the front end and nodejs on the backend.

Here is how I read and create.

My angularjs controller :

```
myApp.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'AuthService', function ($scope, $resource, AuthService) {
  var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');
$scope.meetups = []

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });

  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
     meetup.text = usersOnline;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
      $scope.username = '';
    });
  }
}]);
```

And my api :

```
module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var meetup = new Meetup(req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  meetup.save(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  });
}

module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Meetup.find({}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Help with what exactly? What does your code (not) do?

Comment: It doesn't update the database. I want to modify objects

Comment: Might help if you post the code for the Meetup.save function

Comment: Do you want to modify objects or create? where is your modify code?

Comment: I dont have code to modify. But thats what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    module.exports.update = function (req, res) {
        var id = req.body.id;

      Meetup.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, meetup) {

            meetup.name = req.body.name;

            meetup.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({
                        success: 0,
                        message: 'unable to update: ' + err.message
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        success: 1,
                        message: 'updated',
                        data: meetup
                    });
                }
            });

      });
    }
```

you will hit this API with PUT request with id and other new values you want to update.