# MEAN stack how to find _id from database to send a PUT request

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, document, put

I'm having a problem identifying a 'task' in mongoDB from my frontend angular.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844483/how-to-update-mongodb-with-angular-nodejs) is the most similar to my question but here it just says `req.body.id` and doesn't really explain how they got that.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165805/mongodb-how-to-update-only-one-element-in-the-document) involves what I am trying to do: update one document in a collection upon a click. What it does in the frontend isn't important. I just want to change the status text of the Task from `"Active"` to `"Completed"` onclick.

First I create a task and stick it in my database collection with this code:

```
createTask(): void {
    const status = "Active";
    const taskTree: Task = {
      _id: this._id,
      author: this.username,
      createdBy: this.department,
      intendedFor: this.taskFormGroup.value.taskDepartment,
      taskName: this.taskFormGroup.value.taskName,
      taskDescription: this.taskFormGroup.value.taskDescription,
      expectedDuration: this.taskFormGroup.value.expectedDuration,
      status: status
    };   
    this.http.post("/api/tasks", taskTree).subscribe(res => {
      this.taskData = res;
    });
  }
```

When I make this post to the backend, _id is magically filled in!
I'm just not sure how I can pass the id to the put request in nodejs `router.put('/:id')` when I'm pushing it from the frontend like this:

```
completeTask(): void {
    const status = "Completed";
    const taskTree: Task = {
      _id: this._id,
      author: this.username,
      createdBy: this.department,
      intendedFor: this.taskFormGroup.value.taskDepartment,
      taskName: this.taskFormGroup.value.taskName,
      taskDescription: this.taskFormGroup.value.taskDescription,
      expectedDuration: this.taskFormGroup.value.expectedDuration,
      status: status
    }; 
    console.log(taskTree);


    this.http.put("/api/tasks/" + taskTree._id, taskTree).subscribe(res => {
      this.taskData = res;
      console.log(res);

    });
  }
```

In the template I have a form that's filled in and the data is immediately outputted to a task 'card' on the same page.

When I send the put request from angular, I get a response in the backend just fine of the response I ask for in `task-routes.js`:

```
router.put("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    const taskData = req.body;
    console.log(taskData);

    const task = new Task({
        taskId: taskData._id,
        author: taskData.author,
        createdBy: taskData.createdBy,
        intendedFor: taskData.intendedFor,
        taskName: taskData.taskName,
        taskDescription: taskData.taskDescription,
        expectedDuration: taskData.expectedDuration,
        status: taskData.status
    })

    Task.updateOne(req.params.id, {
        $set: task.status
    },
    {
        new: true
    },
    function(err, updatedTask) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(updatedTask);   
    }
    )

});
```

The general response I get for the updated info is:

```
{
  author: 'there's a name here',
  createdBy: 'management',
  intendedFor: null,
  taskName: null,
  taskDescription: null,
  expectedDuration: null,
  status: 'Completed'
}
```

Now I know _id is created automatically in the database so here when I click create task & it outputs to the 'card', in the console log of `task` after I `save()` it on the post request, `taskId: undefined` comes up. This is all fine and dandy but I have to send a unique identifier from the frontend Task interface so when I send the 'put' request, nodejs gets the same id as was 'post'ed.

I'm quite confused at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out...In case it helps someone here's what finally worked:

First I moved my update function and (patch instead of put) request to my trigger service:

**Trigger Service**

```
tasks: Task[] = [];

updateTask(taskId, data): Observable<Task> {    
    return this.http.patch<Task>(this.host + "tasks/" + taskId, data);
  }
```

I also created a get request in the trigger service file to find all the documents in a collection:

```
getTasks() {
    return this.http.get<Task[]>(this.host + "tasks");
  }
```

**Angular component**

Get tasks in ngOnInit to list them when the component loads:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.triggerService.getTasks().subscribe(
      tasks => {
        this.tasks = tasks as Task[];
        console.log(this.tasks);
      },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
}
```

Update:

```
completeTask(taskId, data): any {
    this.triggerService.updateTask(taskId, data).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

**Angular template (html)**

```
<button mat-button
            class="btn btn-lemon"
            (click)="completeTask(task._id)"
            >Complete Task</button>
// task._id comes from `*ngFor="task of tasks"`, "tasks" being the name of the array 
//(or interface array) in your component file. "task" is any name you give it, 
//but I think the singular form of your array is the normal practice.
```

**Backend Routes**

GET all tasks:

```
router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
  Task.find({})
    .then(tasks => {
      if (tasks) {
        res.status(200).json(tasks);
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "all tasks not found" });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      response.status(500).json({
        message: "Fetching tasks failed",
        error: error
      });
    });
});
```

Update 1 field in specified document (status from "Active" to "Completed"):

```
router.patch("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  const status = "Completed";

  console.log(req.params.id + " IT'S THE ID ");

  Task.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { $set: { status: status } },
    { upsert: true }
  )
    .then(result => {
      if (result.n > 0) {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Update successful!"
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Failed updating the status.",
        error: error
      });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps someone!